# REGEXEXTRACT:value,text function necessary?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Thank you in advance and sorry for the bad English!

I want to separate A Column(number and string)

(Input)

A1:400

A2:abc

B C Column

B1:=IFERROR(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(text(A1,0), "\d+")),"")

C2:=IFERROR(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(text(A2,0), "\D+")),"")

(I want)

B1:400

C2:abc

I want function formula short?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=IFERROR(1*REGEXEXTRACT(A1&"", "\d+"))
```

Answer (score 0):

(integer only)

X:==IFERROR(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(text(A1,0), "\d+")),"")

(decimal)

X:=IFERROR(1*REGEXEXTRACT(A1&"", "\d+"))

○:=IFERROR(1*REGEXEXTRACT(A1&"", "\d+(?:.\d+)?"))

(string)

X:=IFERROR(1*REGEXEXTRACT(A1&"", "\D+"))

○:=IFERROR(   REGEXEXTRACT(A1&"", "\D+"))

○:=IFERROR(    REGEXEXTRACT(A1     , "\D+"))

Comment: excel vba sorry japanese https://osdn.net/projects/sakura-editor/forums/34071/41974/